# how can i join in array same id in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

i want to make like a group array

```
struct songST {
   var singerid:[Int]        
   var  songname:[String]
    var songembeded:[String]
    }

**fist item;**
songST(singerid: "1", songname: ["Its my life"], songembeded: ["url1"]) 

**seconditem=**
songST(singerid: "1", songname: ["Always"], songembeded: ["url2"])

**i want to make join like this**
songST(singerid: "1", songname: ["Its my life","Always"], songembeded: ["url1","url2"])
```

if there was same singerid than will join
how can i do that? Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can improve how data is modeled.

A song consists of the following fields:

- singer id
- song name
- song url

So it would make sense to create a model with exactly those fields, as opposed to creating an array for each of them:

```
struct Song {
    let singerId: Int
    let songName: String
    let songEmbedded: String
}
```

Next, you need a data container for all your songs, which must be grouped by singer. The easiest way is to use a dictionary, whose key is the singer id and the value is an array of `Song`.

Rather than manually creating and handling the dictionary, it's better if a proper data container is created:

```
struct Singers {
    var singers: [Int : [Song]] = [:]

    mutating func addSong(song: Song) {
        if self.singers[song.singerId] == nil {
            self.singers[song.singerId] = []
        }

        self.singers[song.singerId]?.append(song)
    }

    func getSongs(singerId: Int) -> [Song] {
        if self.singers[singerId] == nil {
            return []
        }

        return self.singers[singerId]!
    }
}
```

The `Singers` struct contains a dictionary property, and two method:

- `addSong` adds a song, assigning it to the proper array identified by the key (singer id)
- `getSongs` returns an array of songs for a singer id

Some sample code taken from a storyboard:

```
let s1 = Song(singerId: 1, songName: "Its my life", songEmbedded: "url1")
let s2 = Song(singerId: 1, songName: "Always", songEmbedded: "url2")
let s3 = Song(singerId: 2, songName: "Another", songEmbedded: "url3")

var singers = Singers()

singers.addSong(s1)
singers.addSong(s2)
singers.addSong(s3)

singers.getSongs(1) // Returns an array of 2 items
singers.getSongs(2) // Returns an array of 1 item
singers.getSongs(3) // Returns an empty array (no song for singer 3)
```

Comment: There are several answers on stackoverflow describing different ways of passing parameters between view controllers when using segues. I suggest you to make a search, it would be too long to be described here, and anyway not relevant to this question

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

You asked - "if there was same singerid than will join".

Make a function that uses that if statement:

```
func combineFirstSongST(firstSongST: songST, withSecondSongST secondSongST: songST) -> songST? 
{
  if firstSongST.singerid != secondSongST.singerid 
  {
    return nil
  } 
  else 
  {
    return songST(singerid: firstSongST.singerid, songname: firstSongST.songName + secondSongST.songName, songembeded:   firstSongST.songembeded + secondSongST.songembeded) //single statement
  }
}
```

You should use camel case.